# Error in converting resultjava.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: mysql, linux, database, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am an amateur programmer and I want to get data from a MySql Database which is runnig on a Linux server, but all i get is this Error and I don't know how to handle this. I tried to look for solutions, but i didn't found anything that helped me except for the meaning of this Error.

"Main" Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

/**
 * Created by C on 18.11.2017.
 */

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        String result = "";
        int fd_id;
        String fd_name;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("(server-ip)");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                assert is != null;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine()).append("\n");
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in converting result" + e.toString());
            }


        fd_id = 0;
        fd_name = "";
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                fd_id = json_data.getInt("id");
                fd_name = json_data.getString("login");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextView t = findViewById(R.id.text);
        t.setText("ID: " + fd_id+ "Name: " + fd_name);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
12-15 07:33:46.189 1645-1645/system_process I/SystemServer: StartKeyAttestationApplicationIdProviderService
12-15 07:33:46.607 1645-1645/system_process D/SystemServerTiming: StartKeyAttestationApplicationIdProviderService took to complete: 418ms
12-15 07:36:07.523 1645-1734/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel 'f3dfe06 com.example.celik.test/com.example.celik.test.TestActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
12-15 07:36:07.524 1645-1734/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f3dfe06 com.example.celik.test/com.example.celik.test.TestActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-15 07:36:07.590 1645-2364/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{f3dfe06 u0 com.example.celik.test/com.example.celik.test.TestActivity}
12-15 07:36:07.590 1645-2364/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'f3dfe06 com.example.celik.test/com.example.celik.test.TestActivity (server)'
12-15 07:36:10.149 1645-2364/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.celik.test/.TestActivity bnds=[237,1555][439,1817]} from uid 10024
12-15 07:36:10.211 1645-1657/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4117:com.example.celik.test/u0a80 for activity com.example.celik.test/.TestActivity
12-15 07:36:11.208 1645-1675/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.celik.test/.TestActivity: +1s4ms
```

Debug notes:

```
    12/15 17:55:13: Launching TestActivity
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.celik.test/com.example.celik.test.TestActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.celik.test | com.example.celik.test.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.celik.test | com.example.celik.test.test
Connecting to com.example.celik.test
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.celik.test is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/zygote: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8617', transport: 'socket'
I/chatty: uid=10080(com.example.celik.test) identical 5 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1362)
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/log_tag: Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/log_tag: Error in converting resultjava.lang.NullPointerException
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline

                  [ 12-15 16:55:18.116  4066: 4091 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x98629a00, tid 4091


                  [ 12-15 16:55:18.116  4066: 4091 W/         ]
                  Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x986680a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x986680a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x998c0980)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x986680a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x998c0980)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x986680a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x998c0980)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x986680a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x998c0980)
```

and Permisson:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Instead of Log.e("log_tag", "Error in converting result" + e.toString()) print out the stack trace. Use "e.printStackTrace();"

Comment: Thank you, clinomaniac. I found out, that the Code can not connect to the server, so i don't get any input and this problem occurs. But why have the Code no connection to the server ? Do i need more permissions ?